# Why does gradle ignore my maximum heap size and use the default of 512MB?

Tags: gradle

I have set the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xms1024m -Xmx8192m` and I am getting this error from a Gradle build:

```
2021-04-06T11:49:15.294+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] Error occurred during initialization of VM
2021-04-06T11:49:15.295+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
```

To fix this, I tried adding the following to the top-level `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    // ...

    test {
        minHeapSize = "1g"
        maxHeapSize = "8g"
    }
}
```

Setting the maximum heap size for tests had fixed this problem in the past. But in this case, it didn't. Gradle is still setting the maximum heap size to 512MB, as shown below. (I have replaced some substrings with `****` below.)

```
2021-04-06T11:49:15.188+0100 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'. Working directory: **** Command: ****\java.exe -Djava.security.manager=worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.BootstrapSecurityManager -Dorg.gradle.native=false -Xmx512m **** worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
2021-04-06T11:49:15.188+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Environment for process 'Gradle Test Executor 1': ****
2021-04-06T11:49:15.188+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
2021-04-06T11:49:15.188+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: Gradle Test Executor 1.
2021-04-06T11:49:15.215+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTED
2021-04-06T11:49:15.215+0100 [INFO] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Successfully started process 'Gradle Test Executor 1'
2021-04-06T11:49:15.215+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner] waiting until streams are handled...
2021-04-06T11:49:15.289+0100 [ERROR] [system.err] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xms1024m -Xmx8192m
2021-04-06T11:49:15.294+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] Error occurred during initialization of VM
2021-04-06T11:49:15.295+0100 [QUIET] [system.out] Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
2021-04-06T11:49:15.307+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
2021-04-06T11:49:15.307+0100 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with exit value 1 (state: FAILED)
```

Why is Gradle 6.5.1 ignoring my `maxHeapSize`?

There is another `test` block in one other Gradle file, but no other `maxHeapSize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by both the jacoco and scoverage plugins being enabled in the same Gradle modules. These were Scala modules, so I just removed the jacoco plugin from those modules and then it worked.